# Unable to setup xdebug for PHP in Intellij

Tags: php, intellij-idea, xdebug

I am trying to setup the debugger using xdebug and IntelliJiDEA 14.0.4 with my PHP application  that runs at my localhost for Unit Testing and tracing. i have tried my best but could not able to locate where is the issue.

My phpinfo page shows xdebug support enabled Version 2.4.0.
It is the same version suggested by https://xdebug.org/wizard.php

In IntelliJ I have Run/Debug configrations I have configured "PHP Web Appication" with 
Start url - http://localhost:8081/baskar/index.php 
Servers - 172.20.65.71 : 9000 xdebug
In Validate remote environment - i have given deployment server as Local and validation script path as C:\dev\baskar\Validation. On validate I am getting
!No php.ini file was found
!No debug extension is loaded

My php.ini file settings:

> extension=php_oci8_11g.dll  ; Use with Oracle 11gR2 Instant Client
>   zend_extension=C:/dev/php_5.4/ext/php_xdebug-2.4.0-5.4-vc9.dll
>   [xdebug] xdebug.remote_enable=true xdebug.remote_port=9000
>   xdebug.profiler_enable=1 xdebug.remote_host=172.20.65.71
>   xdebug.profiler_output_dir="C:\dev"
>   xdebug.remote_log=C:\dev\php_5.4\xdebug.log

Please guide me where I went wrong or let me know if you need anyother info. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I would like to provide a generic solution for a very common problem.:
Intellij Ultimate 2018.3 has an excellent Pre-configuracion instructions, with validation (check step 1). Open settings (CTRL+ALT+S) and find it following the selected option in the capture:

[image: php debug wizard]

Take your time, all you need is in these configurations steps.